# Scripts descompilados Oracle 10g

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g

*Dll .NET* é usada para compilar scripts, porém em databases **Oracle 10g** os *scripts* ficam descompilados e é necessário realizar a compilação usando um *SQL Developer*, por exemplo.

*Constatado que isso ocorre somente para Oracle 10g.*

- Por que isso ocorre?
- Como corrigir ou conselhos para encontrar a fonte do problema?

Comment: Qual é exatamente o seu problema?

Comment: No sql plus você pode fazer por exemplo ALTER PROCEDURE E<nome> COMPILE; o sql developer na realidade monta os comandos sql e envia para o banco. Nunca ouvir falar deste descompilador.

Comment: Mesmo utilizando ALTER PROCEDURE <nome> COMPILE o script continua descompilado, executando via cmd continua descompilado também.
O único momento em que ele compilou foi quando cliquei com o botão direito em cima e "compilar", e é garantido que o script está correto. (isso pela IDE SQL developer), pelo PL/SQL Developer ele só compila quando o script é aberto e clicado no botão para executar.
Esse é um caso em que ocorre somente no Oracle 10g